# c# problems with override

Tags: c#

I have a base class that has the following property:

```
public virtual Dictionary<String, int> activity
    {
        get;
        set;

    }
```

A derived class overrides this as such:

```
Dictionary<string, int> myActivity = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"result", 5},
        {"total", 6}
    };


    public override Dictionary<string, int> activity
    {
        get
        {
            return myActivity;
        }

    }
```

I want to call the override dictionary from within the same assembly of the base class, but a different class.

so for example from Class2 I want to call:

```
Class1 c = new Class1();
```

And then try to access dictionary as such:

```
c.activity["result"]
```

I get an error saying it's not within the dictionary?

The derived class is in another assembly...dll file.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `Class1` the base class or the derived class?

Comment: Is Class1 the parent class or the child class? Your examples don't show which code goes with which class name.

Comment: is Class1 base or derived class?

Comment: Exactly where in `Class1` is the dictionary initialized (assuming that is the derived class; not entirely clear from the question)?

Comment: Can you provide the code for all the classes you're talking?

Comment: Hi class1 is in the base class.  As is the calling class.  I want that calling class to call the dictionary, but I want the override version?  Thanks.

Comment: @Darren: please edit the question so that it becomes clear what name refers to what class, and what code goes where.

Comment: It's difficult to interpret the question without seeing the actual class declarations, but this reads as though you've created an instance of the base class.  You need to create an instance of the derived one in order to get the behavior you expect. (This will still work, if the reference variable is the type of the base class. This change of behaviors is what polymorphism is all about.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Class1 c = new Class2();
c.activity["result"]
```

will work you override activity property in Class2 not in Class1

Answer (score 1):

It doesnt sound like the `Class1 c = new Class1();` is the same instance as class where you have instantiated the `Dictionary`

To be able to access the `Dictionary` property with the value, the class you have instantiated must be either the class which instantiates the `Dictionary`, or a class that derives from it.

Comment: Hi, I forgot to mention, the overriden property is actually in another assembly...a dll file.

Comment: @Darren The assembly doesnt matter, it is the class that the property is a member of that matters.
If you create a base class ClassA and have 2 classes that inherit from it ClassB and ClassC, ClassC will not see properties that are overridden in ClassB.
What is more, 2 instances of ClassB will not see the same Instance of the property.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have an dictionary instance declared in Class1 then mark the property abstract. If you do, then just add the value "result" to it. Think clearly on who owns the data between Class1 and Class2. In fact maybe Class1 needs to be just an interface here if it does not intent to actually allocate any data.

Answer (score 0):

You've created an instance of Class1 which if I'm interpreting the question correctly, is your base class (including the class declarations would be helpful). In order for your object c to use the dictionary from Class2, it needs to be created as an instance of Class2.

Your code would then look like this:

Base class:

```
class Class1
{
    public virtual Dictionary<String, int> activity
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

Derived class:

```
class Class2
{
    Dictionary<string, int> myActivity = new Dictionary<string, int>()
    {
        {"result", 5},
        {"total", 6}
    };


    public override Dictionary<string, int> activity
    {
        get
        {
            return myActivity;
        }

    }
}
```

And then the calling code

```
Class1 c = new Class2();
```

At this point, c.activity["result"] will contain the expected result.